# Compile CSHTML to HTML for Webpack Dev Server

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my development workflow, I'm currently using `webpack-dev-server` to create a bundle that is included in an root `index.html` page.  In my production workflow, I use `webpack` to bundle my assets again, but this time include them in an ASP.NET MVC app (using Razor).

What this means is that I have essentially duplicated root views for each workflow: `index.html` for development, and various `.cshtml` files for production.  I'm wondering if there's a way I can compile the `.cshtml` Razor views to an `index.html` page that I can use in my development workflow.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use ASP.Net Core's Webpack integration.

Comment: For various reasons, I cannot in my case.